Inverse Laplace transform of $s^n$
I happened on something in Spiegel's (Schaum's Outlines) Laplace Transform book (which is a great book) that I find strange, and I wonder if anyone can shed some light on it. In problem 11, Chapter 3, we are solving the following initial value problem:
$$
Y'' - tY' + Y = 1, \qquad Y(0)=1, Y'(0) = 2.
$$
Taking Laplace transforms, we end up with $y(s)$ containing a term $\frac{e^{-s^2/2}}{s^2}$. Now the book expands this function into a power series, and inverts the $1/s^2$ part of this expansion. The rest of the expansion is basically thrown away, because it says that the inverse Laplace transform of $s^k$ is $0$ for $k \geq 0$.
I don't find this very satisfying. First of all, shouldn't these be derivatives of the delta function? But even ignoring that, most Laplace transforms can be expanded into series, for instance $\frac{1}{1-s} = 1 + s + s^2 + \ldots$, but this clearly does not invert to $0$.
Can anyone explain this?
Thanks,
Greg

$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\lefts^n\right=\frac{x^{-n-1}}{\Gamma (-n)}$ which is zero for non-negative integer values of $n$ because of the poles of the gamma term in the denominator at non-negative integer values of $n$. The Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_x\left\frac{x^{-n-1}}{\Gamma(-n)}\right=s^n$ is only valid for $\Re(n)<0\land \Re(s)>0$.

Thanks for that. But then, why does it not work for $\frac{1}{1-s}$? Is it because it's not equal to its power series on all of $Re(s)>0$? That occurred to me as possibly the reason since $e^{-s^2/2}$ is entire.
